# Upgraded hard drive in MacBook, can I just drag applications over to new applications folder?

Tags: mac, macbook

I just upgraded my hard drive in my old MacBook. I have both hard drives connected so could I just drag an app from applications folder on old drive into applications folder on new drive and it would just work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really not the way to do it. Some would, some wouldn't, none of your prefs would come across with it. You'd end up with a mess.

You were given the best opportunity as you set up the new drive - which I'm assuming you did from scratch - right at the point it asked you to make the first account. You would have been presented with an opportunity to Migrate from another drive, another computer, a Time Machine backup etc.

As you ignored this, now you have an additional problem.
You can manually launch the Migration Assistant, in Applications/Utilities, but doing it that way will make a new account to migrate to, meaning you will then have two to merge.

If you've only just started on this new drive, tbh your best bet would be to wipe it & start over. Do the migration when it first asks.

Your alternative would be to use something like [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com). Boot to your old drive, clone to your new.
The downside of this method is that there is no 'sanity check' process; you simply get an identical copy of your old drive on your new drive.